# Html to JQuery link conversion

Tags: jquery

please help me to convert reqular html links to jquery. Why this doesn not work ?

I try this JS code in HEAD part of the document (after jquery is embedded):

```
$('.ext1').replaceWith(function(){return'<a href="'+$(this).data('link')+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a>';})
```

And HTML part is

```
<span class="ext1" data-link="Write URL here">link text</span>
```

Comment: Make sure your script runs after the `<span>` in the file or that you use doc.ready

Comment: well the code needs to run when the document is ready or it is not doing to find any elements.Putting it in the head like that is not going to locate any elements because you are looking for them before they are generated.

Answer (score 0):

As @epascarello said, you need to run your code when then document is ready. So you code need to look something like:

```
<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.ext1')
      .replaceWith(function() {
        return '<a href="'+$(this).data('link')+'">'+$(this).html()+'</a>';
      });
    });
</script>
```

For more info about the document ready function, check [this](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).